# Can you omit only a subject following “as long as?”

Tags: grammaticality, omissibility, subject-drop

Can you leave a subject following “as long as” out, keeping the verb followed alive?

> - I can read it aloud for you as long as <strike>it</strike> is in English.
> - So you can watch any movies as long as <strike>they</strike> have subtitles on?

And why is that? Are there any authoritative grammar rules to support the reason?

---

I searched up some grammar ideas about “as” but they only confuse me. I can’t even judge whether these are related or not.

- ['As can be seen ...' <--- Can English have a tensed clause without a Subject?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429740/as-can-be-seen-can-english-have-a-tensed-clause-without-a-subject/429906)
- [Where is the subject in "as was traditional for unmarried women"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373692/where-is-the-subject-in-as-was-traditional-for-unmarried-women/373696)
- [Omission of subject](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274524/omission-of-subject)

Comment: No, you can't. I don't know why.

Comment: In English you cannot do this.  I am guessing in your own language you can do this.  So this is yet another difference between the two languages.

Comment: Syntactically, ***as long as*** is pretty much interchangeable with ***if***, where I think you can omit both subject ***and*** verb. I have no problem with *I only watch foreign films **if subtitled*** (reduced from *if **they are** subtitled*), but offhand I can't think of any similar contexts where that elided verb isn't a copula (= TO BE), or where only the subject is omitted.

Comment: @FumbleFingers not *fully* interchangeable: it sounds somewhat non-fluent to say "you can watch any movies as long as subtitles on" or "I can read it aloud for you as long as in English".

Comment: @Chappo: Like I said, ***pretty much*** (not ***fully***) interchangeable. For example, I can (just about! :) live with *My party next week will have a live band playing in the garden **if not wet***, but I couldn't be doing with ***as long as*** instead of ***if*** there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I hope the condition here is the *weather* not being wet, rather than your choice of band ;-)

Comment: @Chappo: I had been planning on having a stand-up comic do a turn in the garden ***if not dry**.* But the only comedians available at short notice were all dry / sarcastic / ironic types, so I decided to have a band instead.

Comment: *I can read it aloud for you **as long as** possible*. There is no subject following the phrase there. (Unless you want to claim it's just elided.) So, it's certainly possible to omit a subject in *some* constructions. Or are you only asking about the two sentences in your question?

Comment: @JasonBassford I clarified the question: I’m asking about omitting such a subject only, like the two sentences above.

Comment: Given most of the answers are “It just sounds off.”, I think this question boils down to basics of the English grammar. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @КонстантинВан It's still not clear to me what you're asking. Do you mean only in those sentences constructed like the two you give—or do you mean in *any* sentence that uses *as long as*?

Comment: @JasonBassford In any sentence that has “as long as.” I wanted to know if such a general rule exists.

Comment: @КонстантинВан I see. Then my original comment still stands: *I can read it aloud for you **as long as** possible.*